# Is it possible to fully replace an interface from an external package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

**Edit**: The reason I want this is as a workaround for a [Typescript bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55026)

I'm trying to replace the type parameters for an interface from an external module, which is declared as follows in their `.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace TheirNamespace {
  interface Foo<GenericType = any> {
  }
}
```

with the following in my code:

```
declare global {
    export namespace TheirNamespace {
        export interface Foo<GenericType = any, ExtraType extends object = never> {
    }
}
```

Without the defaults for type, I get a `All declarations of 'Foo' must have identical type parameters.` error. Which is understandable.

So my goal is to replace the original interface entirely with one that extends it, rather than augment it. That is, functionally accomplish this pseudocode: `TheirNamespace.Foo = MyInterfaceThatExtendsFoo`, such that anything using `Foo` will actually point at my interface instead (for IntellIsense).

Currently my solution is to have a separate interface and use module augmentation to change the return type of methods in TheirNamespace, but I'd prefer to only have one interface.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: My question would be why? Is there something wrong with the code in the external module that needs to be fixed and you are trying to patch over it until they do?

Comment: @ChrisBarr I'm making a plugin to extend their functionality. However, there's a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55026) in TypeScript that causes the second generic to be lost.

Comment: sounds like something to put [in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: fair call, thanks